# Sails.js error when lifting the server

Tags: sails.js

```
error: A hook (`controllers`) failed to load!
error: A hook (`policies`) failed to load!
error: `include-all` attempted to `require(C:\Users\Jigar\Documents\GitHub\Assessment_3_AIP_32549\api\controllers\SessionController.js)`, but an error occurred::
Details:Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
\\?\C:\Users\Jigar\Documents\GitHub\Assessment_3_AIP_32549\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\bcrypt_lib.node
    at Error (native)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:597:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jigar\Documents\GitHub\Assessment_3_AIP_32549\node_modules\bcrypt\bcrypt.js:6:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jigar\Documents\GitHub\Assessment_3_AIP_32549\api\controllers\SessionController.js:8:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
```

Comment: My guess is that the installed Node modules are not correct for the environment you're running, so I would try removing your `node_modules` folder, and running `npm cache clean` and `npm install`.  But it would help if you could provide some more information, like the version of Windows, Node, NPM and Sails that you're using.